# My indesign page is really small and I dont know how to fix it

Tags: adobe-indesign

[image]Ive been working on a project lately and all of a sudden one or my pages shrunk. I tried to fix the pasteboard and to delete the page itself. Nothing I've done so far works and I don't have time to set up a new Documeny. Please Help!!!!

[image]

Comment: Don't you have a backup file to replace just this page?

Comment: What exactly is the first picture a picture of? I see a big white space, a square grey space, and a black background (?), but what are those things? And what is that tiny little blue thingamajig in the centre of the grey? Is that the content of the page?

Answer (score 2):

The strangely large shadow on that small page looks like a bug. I've seen InDesign documents go bad before with similar issues.

But before panicking, backup your document and try this:

- Unlock any locked layers and objects.
- Right click in the *Pages* panel.
- Select *Apply Master to Pages...*.
- Apply your *A-master* to the page in question (7).

If this doesn't work, you could see if it's possible to delete the trouble page if you delete a wider range of pages. Page 6-11 for example. Or page 2-11. If it's possible you could:

- Create a new document with the same dimensions and 11 pages (don't you need the 12th?).
- For each spread: *Select All* and *Copy* in the old document, then *Paste in Place* in the new document.
- Delete page 2-11 in the old document (if it's possible).
- Insert 10 new pages.
- Copy all the content back to the old document from the new, one spread at a time.

If it's not possible to delete pages you could experiment with:

- Changing page size using the *Edit page size* button in the *Pages* panel.
- Dragging the page to another position to see if anything happens.
- Check the *Margins and Columns* settings for the page. Maybe there is some strange numbers there? The margins must fit inside the page, but sometimes this is buggy.
- Enter *Edit > Preferences > Guides & Pasteboard*. Try setting the margins to something large. Like 1000 mm or more - you can always switch back afterwards. Sometimes objects end up way outside the pasteboard and cause problems. *Select All* to check for rogue objects.

If all else fails you probably need to make a new document from scratch. But be aware that you can import all styles and colors from the old document, and then copy/paste the content from the old document. It's probably just the margins you need to reenter.